# pynput keyboard listener causes delays

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, pynput

I am making a program that toggles on and off by a certain key on the keyboard (using pynput). I placed the keyboard listener loop in the first thread, and the action loop in the second. 
The problem is that after I start the code, it doesn't listen to the keyboard immediately, only after 9-10 seconds have passed. And sometimes it refuses to react to Esc button, and sometimes it works. How to fix the lag? Is the code ok?

```
from threading import Thread
from pynput import keyboard
import time

flag = False
kill = False

def on_press(key):
    global flag
    global kill

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('a'):
        print('pressed A')
        flag = not flag
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        kill = True
        return False

def thr2():
    print('joining...')
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listen:
        listen.join()

def thr1():
    while True:
        if kill:
            break
        if flag:
            print('looping....')
            time.sleep(0.4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = Thread(target=thr1)
    thread2 = Thread(target=thr2)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the actual delay is coming from the pynput keyboard.Listener context handler itself. I can't tell you whats happening under the hood but the delay is not coming from the way you are managing your threads.

```
# pynput library creating keyboard.Listener thread causes the delay
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listen:  
    print('listen thread created')  # This does not happen until after the delay
    listen.join()
```

You may want to rephrase the question so that it is specific to pynput keyboard.Listener

Comment: have you tried running the code? do you experience the same lag? I noticed that delay doesn't happen unless I put it under the thread BUT when I use multiprocessing instead and change Thread(target=...) to Process(target=...) the delay is gone. But I cannot use multiprocessing because it does not recognize global variables for some reason and this is what I am trying to figure out right now. Do you by chance know how to pass 'flag' and 'kill' variables between processes?

Comment: I did experience the same delay when running it both within a thread and outside of a thread.  The fact that it is already in a thread should not matter because the keyboard.Listen handler is creating a new thread anyway.  Using multiprocessing instead of threads makes things difficult because Processes do not have explicit access to anything that exists outside of them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works nicely with multiprocessing:

```
import sys
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Event
from functools import partial


def thr2(kill_event, flag_event):

    def on_press(kill_event, flag_event, key):
        if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('a'):
            print('pressed A')
            if flag_event.is_set():
                flag_event.clear()
            else:
                flag_event.set()
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            print('esc')
            kill_event.set()
            sys.exit(0)

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=partial(on_press, kill_event, flag_event)) as listen:
        listen.join()


def thr1(kill_event, flag_event):
    while True:
        if kill_event.is_set():
            print('kill')
            sys.exit(0)
        if flag_event.is_set():
            print('looping....')
            sleep(0.4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    kill_event = Event()
    flag_event = Event()

    thread1 = Process(target=thr1, args=(kill_event, flag_event))
    thread2 = Process(target=thr2, args=(kill_event, flag_event))

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    thread1.join()  # Join processes here to avoid main process exit
    thread2.join()
```